# Cambio de eclipse a visual studio code

Tags: eclipse, vscode

Hasta ahora programaba en php desde el IDE eclipse pero viendo todas la ventajas de VS Code decidí cambiarme. He conseguido mas o menos todas las funcionalidades que tenia en eclipse pero hay una que se me resiste.

En eclipse si hacia CTRL+click en la llamada a un metodo me llevaba al metodo en cuestion, pero en VS Code no encuentro como hacerlo. Pongo un ejemplo.

***Modelo***

```
class UserModel{ 
   function getAll(){
      ***codigo***
   }
}
```

***Controller***

```
use UserModel;
class UserController{
   function get(){
      $user = new UserModel();
      return $user->getAll();
   }
}
```

En eclipse (en el controlador) si hacia CTRL+click en getAll() me llevaba al metodo del archivo model.

Comment: Yo utilizo vsCode para mis desarrollos en Angular y la función que tú mencionas SÍ existe. Sólo tienes que asegurarte que la solución/proyecto con la que trabajas la abriste como un "Workspace/Espacio de Trabajo".

Comment: En php y por lo menos que he visto ahasta ahora. Abriendolo como un workspace, solo funciona si el metodo esta en el mismo archivo. Si esta en un archivo distinto no funciona.